# Resistance and Temperature

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance

I want to ask something related to resistance and temperature.
I know that when the temperature is rising, the resistance will also rise.
I am wondering, there should be a certain point where something will go wrong.
So let's only pay attention to the resistance before the substance breakdown or melting.
Let's say the temperature is higher than the Curie temperature, what will happen to the resistance when the substance is heated higher than the Curie temperature? Does it cause a permanent damage when it cools down? Or what happened to the resistance after it cools down?
If something happened (e.g. the resistance is now higher/lower at the normal temperature, etc), what is the reason for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the linear relation between resistance and temperature is only an approximation (see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/570473/247642) for discussion). I particular, the behavior of resistance at low temperatures have nothing to do with it, and very much depends on the material properties (see [here for examples](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/672976/247642)). One crucial aspect is that resistance depends a lot on various material imperfections (lattice imperfections, impurities, etc.) - these are certainly subject to change when heating and subsequently cooling a material, and will depend not only on the original material, but also on how it is heated and cooled.

**Remark:** *Curie temperature* is a concept characterizing magnetic materials - not just any material. Some discussion of magnetic alloys is present in the posts linked, but you may want to ask a more specific question.